# Processing intent with camera image between two Activities and passing it to marker on Google Maps API does not work

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Android and working on an Android app. The app has two activities: An Edit Activity and a Maps Activity.

In the Edit activity, the user can input data and take a picture from the Android phone, which works fine. The other Activity is a Maps Activity, where Markers on a map are displayed.

The markers on the map contain a bitmap, which also works fine. The part that isn´t working, is the part that the camera picture is placed on the marker instead of the bitmap graphic.

The image from the camera is displayed in an image view for the Edit Activity, which works fine.

The part that is not working is passing the camera intent to the other activity and placing the content of the intent on the marker.

Here´s the Edit Activity (a lot of code is commented out):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.R.attr.data;
import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE;



public class EditActivity extends Activity {


    public static int count = 0;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_LOC = "location";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_LAT = "latlng";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_PIC = "picture";
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editactivity);
        PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
        helper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        final LatLng latlng = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("location");
        //final MarkerImage markerImage = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
        final EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        final EditText date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        final EditText location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        final Button camerabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        final Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)
                        );
                if (title.getText() != null) {
                    marker.title(title.getText().toString());
                }
                if (date.getText() != null) {
                    marker.getPosition();
                    Log.d("String Value of Marker:", String.valueOf(marker));
                }

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("marker", marker);
                resultIntent.putExtra("picture", getCameraImage);
                Log.d("Längen-und Breitengrad:", String.valueOf(marker));
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }

        });


        // Here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store
        // pics taken by the camera using this application.
        //final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
        //File newdir = new File(dir);
        //newdir.mkdirs();

        //final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        /*if (getCameraImage.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();


            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                // The user might already exist in the database (i.e. the same user created multiple posts).
                //long markerId = addOrUpdateMarker(marker.user);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(KEY_MARKER_ID, id);
                values.put(KEY_MARKER_TITLE, String.valueOf(title));
                values.put(KEY_MARKER_NAME, String.valueOf(name));
                values.put(KEY_MARKER_LOC, String.valueOf(location));
                values.put(KEY_MARKER_DATE, String.valueOf(date));
                // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
                db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_MARKERS, null, values);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to add post to database");
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }

            /*File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
        /*capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
                // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
                // and likewise.

                //count++;
                //String file = dir+count+".jpg";
                //File newfile = new File(file);
                //try {
                //    newfile.createNewFile();
               //}
               // catch (IOException e)
               // {
               // }

                //Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                //cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        });
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
              //  ".jpg",         /* suffix */
              //  storageDir      /* directory */
        //);

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        //mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        //return image;
    }

        /*@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);



                }
            }

        /*if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");

        }*/

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }


}
```

Here´s the Maps Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import gmbh.webagenten.recycling.PostsDatabaseHelper;
import gmbh.webagenten.recycling.SQLiteSampleActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static gmbh.webagenten.recycling.R.attr.title;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int EDIT_REQUEST = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get singleton instance of database

        //PostsDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance((Context) this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1);
        this.mMap = map;
        try {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            LatLng hamburg = new LatLng(53.551085, 9.993682);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hamburg).title("Marker in Hamburg")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hamburg));
            //PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
            //helper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Log.d(TAG, "Database in use");
         }

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {

                Intent edit = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
                Log.d("Längen-und Breitengrad:", String.valueOf(latLng));

                MapsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case (EDIT_REQUEST) : {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = data.getParcelableExtra("marker");
                    MarkerOptions markerImage = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    //mMap.addMarker(markerImage);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */


/*

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        try {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            LatLng hamburg = new LatLng(53.551085, 9.993682);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hamburg).title("Marker in Hamburg"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hamburg));
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        }
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {
                Intent edit = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
                MapsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
        });


    }

*/
```

The XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#222"
        android:id="@+id/llMarker">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMarker"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
        <item>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </item>

    </LinearLayout>
</selector>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Location"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Camera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
```

As I am new to Android, I am stuck with this problem for a longer time now. Any help or hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem . What I got the mistake is , you are not able to get the bitmap to the next activity , you have set the data to the imageview in edit activity and when you are opening the map activity, that data is lost ,

what you have to do is:
1. pass the bitmap to the map activity from edit activity
2. get the bitmap to the map activity and then show the bitmap to the map.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.R.attr.data;
import static android.R.attr.id;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE;



public class EditActivity extends Activity {


    public static int count = 0;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_LOC = "location";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_LAT = "latlng";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_MARKER_PIC = "picture";
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editactivity);
        PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
        helper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        final LatLng latlng = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("location");
        //final MarkerImage markerImage = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
        final EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        final EditText date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        final EditText location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        final Button camerabutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        final Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)
                        );
                if (title.getText() != null) {
                    marker.title(title.getText().toString());
                }
                if (date.getText() != null) {
                    marker.getPosition();
                    Log.d("String Value of Marker:", String.valueOf(marker));
                }

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("marker", marker);
                resultIntent.putExtra("picture", getCameraImage);
                intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", photo);          // passing the bitmap to the next activity . and retrieve it to the next activity
                Log.d("Längen-und Breitengrad:", String.valueOf(marker));
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }

        });



  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           `photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the map activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import gmbh.webagenten.recycling.PostsDatabaseHelper;
import gmbh.webagenten.recycling.SQLiteSampleActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static gmbh.webagenten.recycling.R.attr.title;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int EDIT_REQUEST = 1;
    Bitmap bmp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get singleton instance of database

        Intent intent = getIntent(); 
        bmp = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");      // getting the bitmap data from the edit activity.

        //PostsDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance((Context) this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1);
        this.mMap = map;
        try {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            LatLng hamburg = new LatLng(53.551085, 9.993682);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hamburg).title("Marker in Hamburg")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(hamburg));
            //PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
            //helper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Log.d(TAG, "Database in use");
         }

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {

                Intent edit = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
                Log.d("Längen-und Breitengrad:", String.valueOf(latLng));

                MapsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case (EDIT_REQUEST) : {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = data.getParcelableExtra("marker");
                    MarkerOptions markerImage = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    //mMap.addMarker(markerImage);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the updated code, Hope it help .Kindly check it and let me know.

Comment: Hi @rajendra, thank you for your effort - however, the code still produces the same result, so it isn´t working as desired...  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon) should be replaced by the camera image and that doesn´t work. Any further help or hints would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi , you have not to decode the bitmap , but to get it from intent send from edit activity. Intent intent = getIntent(); 
        bmp = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");

Comment: intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", photo);   // passing the bitmap to the next activity . and retrieve it to the next activity

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, it isn´t working. I get the following error message:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {gmbh.webagenten.recycling/gmbh.webagenten.recycling.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: bitmap

Comment: Hi , I guess you have not passed the bitmap data from edit activity.

Comment: thank yo so far - ok. What is missing in he edit activity? Can you update the code? I am not so experienced with Android. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi, kindly mail your code me at rajendra@skydevelopers.net , I will mail you the corrected code. Thanks